# How can I prevent sudden audio peaks while gaming?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

While playing intense first-person-shooter games often a grenade goes off near my head.  The problem, is that I want to maintain my longer hearing while still hear the guy who sneaks up behind me.

Is there software I could use to deafen **loud** blasts and amplify **quiet** footsteps?

Edit: I think I'm looking for dynamic range compressing software.

Comment: Well, what you want is a [dynamic range compressor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression). I don't know if there are programs to do this on the fly for Windows without noticeable delay, but the outboard equipment is better anyways :)

Comment: well then that is exactly what I'm looking for.  I have a very, very fast computer (if that means anything here).

Comment: The point is, you have to run your game's audio through such a compressor, and *then* to your speakers. I don't know if this kind of software audio routing is possible in Windows.

Comment: Yes, I use windows.  In the past, for other reasons, I used virtual audio (I forget) software, something like [this](http://superuser.com/questions/117625/how-to-create-a-virtual-audio-device-and-stream-audio-input-with-it)... essentially it let me direct audio to virtual devices...  Would that fix the problem of going from the game directly to the speakers?

Comment: Yes, VAC seems to do the trick for that. You only need to find out how to insert an effect into this chain, maybe even using Audacity and a VST effect.

Comment: "insert an effect into this chain" by chain I assume you mean as the sound goes from the game>virtual>software>speakers, right?  And what kind of effect are you referring to?

Comment: Just lower the volume till when grenades don't hurt your ears anymore, a sudden grenade isn't likely to damage your hearing unless you have the volume way to loud. When there are people throwing grenades and firing, I bet you shouldn't even care about footsteps at that moment. If there is no action on the scene, you automatically get to hear the quiet footsteps better; there is really no need to raise them, or you would be the first to do so. A proper professional headset or in-ear equipment is a must, rather than making the whole sound environment more noisy...

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/31580/is-there-a-way-of-leveling-compressing-the-sound-system-wide for the same on Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Until somebody comes along with the real answer, I'll explain here (it's just better than a long thread of comments).

You're looking for a [**compressor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression). It will lower the loud signals and therefore make lessen the dynamic range of the audio signal, which means that you can turn up the overall volume.

Compressors are available as built-in effects, for example in [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), but also come as effect units for common effect frameworks such as [Steinberg's VST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology). You'll just have to find a free compressor, and for VST, I guess there are plenty.

Your setup would then route the audio from the game to the effect, and *then* to the final output.

> *Game* → *Virtual audio output* → *VST or other effect* → *Real audio ouput*

Given a fast enough machine, this should happen in real time. The only problem is that I don't know Windows well enough to be able to help you here. Maybe with [Virtual Audio Cable](https://superuser.com/questions/117625/how-to-create-a-virtual-audio-device-and-stream-audio-input-with-it)? Maybe by routing it into Audacity playing in the background? Can it process live sound?

If you're still up for a hardware solution, there are compressors built into Hi-Fi A/V receivers, and outboard equipment is available too. Like [this one](http://www.behringer.com/EN/Products/MDX1600.aspx).

Comment: +1 (you deserve it).  I might be mistaken, but I'm not sure audacity can process live sound.

I noticed that windows allows for some "enhancements" (see [this](http://imgur.com/YqfuV) ).  Could one of those work for me?  I'm just a bit hesitant when it comes to picking software to download (the VAC and the plugin)

Comment: Not these, but the one Tom Wijsman linked to above – that *should* do the trick as well, but it's not configurable.

Comment: Not these?  What do you mean by that?

Comment: Not the ones you showed me in your screenshot. They just emulate some room acoustics.

Comment: Please note that introducing virtual output and a VST (that does analysis so might need a buffer) into the audio chain can result in a small delay in audio, something you most likely don't want during gaming. If any, try to keep the audio chain as small as possible by directly applying an effect rather than redirecting the audio. If any, a hardware solution could help if delay were your problem...

Comment: @Tom You're definitely right, but it probably depends on the performance of the rig itself and the quality of the software used. I have no idea of any practical numbers here, but on a modern gaming machine, shouldn't be *that* bad? Does Windows provide a plug-in functionality for its "Enhancements"?

Comment: @slhck: I don't know about the plug-in functionality for the Enhancements but given that there has been success in listing values there I believe it's either available from the Windows API or Windows Driver Development Kit. As for the performance, I know DJ software with the ASIO4ALL drivers gets the latency quite low but DJs still have to buy external audio equipment to get a much better latency. Adding a virtual audio output between that introduces some extra delay, which might be enough to have a noticeable difference between what you see and hear.

Comment: @slhck: Please note that there is still a notion of difference between performance and latency; if I press a button it takes some delay before a incredibly fast calculation starts to compute a result, a sound played is similar to that but goes the other way around. Different systems have different latencies, a fast gaming rig doesn't necessary have a better latency than an occasional multi media laptop. [DPC Latency Checker](http://www.thesycon.de/deu/latency_check.shtml) and [LatencyMon](http://www.resplendence.com/latencymon) are useful tools regarding this...

Comment: As a last note, as a virtual audio output is a driver it would be added to the latency reported by these tools when it is in use. Proper configuration of the virtual audio output settings probably could help in decreasing the delay. DJs need low latency to respond to their audio fast enough, Gamers are not much different...

Answer (score 11):

In the Sound configuration, see the options of your playback device.

[image]

Comment: can I assume this would also increase very soft sounds (ex. footsteps)? Can I monitor its effect live?

Comment: Yes, it should. Just (un)check the button and click apply...

Comment: Can I monitor its effectiveness?

Comment: Nevermind, it isn't strong enough (I still hear very, very loud blasts).

Comment: @wizlog: Decreasing your volume should fix that problem.

Comment: The "Enhancements" tab doesn't exist for me on Windows 10. I'm on OEM hardware, and I have the latest drivers.

Answer (score 4):

While a roll-your-own solution may be possible, there is a commercial program that operates like a far more advanced version of Windows' built in "Loudness Equalization": [Breakaway Audio Enhancer](http://store.claessonedwards.com/product_p/bap-002.htm) is a real-time multi-band dynamic range compressor, and if the $30 USD cost is not an objection, it would be the easiest way to accomplish what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Nice solution and Price!

Answer (score 2):

With the Audigy sound cards, back in XP, and the full sound software package, a person could create thier own "compressor" "effect" using the AGC (automatic Gain control) effect. I have done it, it can pretty seriously AVC (automatic volume control) the audio to the point of ruining a movie completly.

To do it was pretty deep, you would run the "audio console" get into the EAX effect. Yes, the same ones that were used to do the Ambiance and other useless stuff, then in Special FX, in there is a Normaliser effect.  Each "effect" can have multiple filters in it. The normaliser effect has applied to it a "Creative AGCCompressor".  to make my own "normaliser" I could create a new effect , and put just creatives compressor in as a filter, adjust things , and finnaly get exactally what your talking about.

One caveat, pinning it through that graph?? (processing the sound through another filter) there is a small delay added to the sound, probably around 22-30ms although I did not measure it.

Creative did not update the whole audigy package for Win7, but some users hacked up the installers so it could install the whole audio package into windows 7. Because Windows decided to put thier own junk in there , I have no idea yet what kind of conflicts and delay it would have.

---

On the other computer with TVtuner, We also use a AVC originally designed for television viewing and normalising of  the commertials, it is a stereo analog (rca) processing box that did only one thing, take a signal in and AVC (auto volume control). It reacts slower, and varies volume by much larger quantities than a "Pro" compression alogrythm.  I still use it for the computer that has a tv tuner in it.  There is very little time delay when using this external analog box thing.

I am not making the hardware or the processes, but we were always analising 3-4 things when dealing with it. And the cute tech terms were not helpfull, like "attack" "gain" and "delay"  I just wanted what you wanted.

1) How far out of sync did the audio get, because it takes way to long to process the audio , seperate from the video.  Try to find that in the specs :-)

2) How It raises the volume back up after louder sounds, is it immediate, or slowly. There is a balance here that many "digital" things cant pull off.

3) How quick does it react to loud sound, so it doesnt blow my head off.  The digital is processing the actual data before heard, could harshly clip the loud stuff, the analog not as fast.

4) How much does it gain the sound. Big balance here, sometimes it needs to gain many times the original, to normalise. Sometimes just being able to hear without having Theatre level sound.

Many of the "Pro" hardware compression alogrythms act more like clippers, are set to very short delays, can be pretty harsh on the sound, and do not work well as AVCs.  Here I ID those as "compression" (the pro term) The ones that are "usefull" for volume control I call AVC.  So much so that the pro "compressors" that we attempted to use for TV and video were usually worse than leaving the signal alone.  They were more like fast digital sound mulchers :-)

So in conclusion there are hardware sound cards, that via software,  do a Heavy AGC/AVC by routing digital data through filters. It is also possible to have an external digital  or analog type AVC without the computer exisiting in the process. Both in "pro" devices, and in more consumer oriented.