# Play a sound over the microphone stream?

Tags: microphone, audio-streaming

This is not to spam someone. My friend wants to hear something over my microphone while retaining the quality (obviously playing it through my microphone using speakers would sound horrible).

Is there a program to play my sounds over my microphone?

EDIT: Software only please. I have no "What U Hear"

Comment: wait. are you using your microphone *as* speakers or... trying to passthrough microphone input out to your speakers?

Comment: I think he wants a way to send the sound to his friend.. which sounds to me like transferring an audio file, if it isn't live.

Comment: Similar: http://superuser.com/questions/117625/how-to-create-a-virtual-audio-device-and-stream-audio-input-with-it