# Set up a virtual capture device using ALSA

Tags: linux, audio, recording, alsa

I am looking to set up a radio stream on my local network using a Linux box with ALSA. My first idea was to just have it capture the sound output, but this can be annoying for several reasons. (For instance, if another program decides to play a sound, it would be broadcast as well. Also, I want to be able to keep the stream running even if I decide to switch players.)

The ideal option would be to set up some kind of virtual sound card with ALSA. The music players would be configured to use it as a sound card and VLC would be configured to use it as a capture device.

There is a very similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/117625/how-to-create-a-virtual-audio-device-and-stream-audio-input-with-it). I want to do basically the same thing using ALSA in a Linux environment. I just need some basic info on if this functionality exists and a simple way to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the `snd-aloop` module to get such a virtual sound card.