# Does PulseAudio work on Windows just like on Linux?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, pulse-audio

When I'm searching something like this on Google all I'm seeing are only pages with keywords [linux, pulseaudio]. I mean ability to configure output stream of one app to be redirected to input stream of another app. So, I decided to ask "unique" (or maybe not) question here.

Target OS is Windows Server.

By the way, if there is similar and free app for Windows which does the job just like PulseAudio on Linux, please go ahead, recommend it but do not advertise it like an agent.

Also, any video tutorial for this are welcome :)

Next question is off topic but if you have answer that's would be great:
Can PulseAudio work (do the same stuff) if Windows Server doesn't have audio card installed?

Thanks forward for any reply!

EDIT: in another question which someone pointed this as duplicate, there is no information about PulseAudio software. And yes, that's very old. We are close to 2016, I can't believe there is nothing new since 2014 (based on last answer to that question). All I receive in comments - opinions without experience for what I've asked for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a virtual audio device and stream audio input with it](http://superuser.com/questions/117625/how-to-create-a-virtual-audio-device-and-stream-audio-input-with-it)

Comment: There is no information about PulseAudio. Official page states that Windows is supported: https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/PulseAudio/ I would like to see someone's experience on this. Most  software on that page you've pointed are not free or limited for free use.

Comment: I'd stick with native Windows solutions. Audio stack in Windows and Linux is very different, and I doubt that PulseAudio devs did something more than basic tests to ensure compatibilty. But if you insist, here is [setup guide for PulseAudio on Windows](https://parseq.co.uk/wordpress/archives/setting-up-pulseaudio-1-0-beta-for-windows). That's probably is the best you can get.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll give a try and answer it by myself.

Answer (score 2):

There's a version of Pulseaudio that is kind of old and apparently doesn't record easily with Windows 10 but I got to playback fine.  I was using Docker and routing locally but the process/setup is the same.

I was able to get playback on Windows using pulseaudio.exe.

1] Download pulseaudio for windows: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Ports/Windows/Support/

2] Uncompress and change the config files.

2a] Add the following line to your $INSTALL_DIR/etc/pulse/default.pa:

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=$HOST_IP
```

Where $HOST_IP is your host.  Alternately you could use the following which opens the host up to all traffic.  There are middle roads here too.

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp listen=0.0.0.0 auth-anonymous=1
```

2b] Change $INSTALL_DIR/etc/pulse//etc/pulse/daemon.conf line to read:
    exit-idle-time = -1

This will keep the daemon open after the last client disconnects.

3) Run pulseaudio.exe

4) In the host's shell:

```
export PULSE_SERVER=tcp:127.0.0.1
```